# Algorithm to find positive definite matrix given conditions.

Tags: matrices, algorithms

I want an algorithm that always find one solution for the given problem below:
Given a positive n length vector, **b**, a n vector of 1 values, **u**:

*I want to determine B, matrix n * n, positive definite as:*

**B*u=b**

The problem is that I have n*n unknown(the elements of B) with constraint(positive definiteness). I just want an algorithm to fix some values and have B.

Thank you for your help,

Regards

Comment: I guess you mean with this: _Given a n length vector, b, a n vector of 1 values, u_   both times a column vector of dimension $n$. Why a definite or semi definite matrix as solution?

Comment: No, u is a 1 n by 1 vector.

Comment: I want B definite positive because I have to use it as the second member of Ljapunov equation and i need that my solution is positive definite so B needs to be definite positive.

Comment: Semi definite programming isn't enough ?

Comment: I don't have a solution, but just want to point out, $B$ does not always exist. For example, since $B$ is positive definite, if $B$ exists, we have $u^{T}b=u^{T}Bu>0$. So if the sum of all the elements of $b$ is not positive, there will be no such $B$ you are seeking.

Comment: Davcha: I think it can be I have to check but in the doubt I will program positive definite.

Comment: Indominus: You are right, I just forgot to add to my post that b is positive(by definition of my problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume you want $B$ to be symmetric positive definite. Let
$$B = \sum_i \lambda_i v_i v_i^T$$
You require the $\lambda_i > 0$.
Let $v_1 = \alpha b$ and $\lambda_1 = 1$, so that $\lambda_1 \alpha^2 bb^T u = b$.
This requires that
$$\alpha = \frac{1}{\sqrt{b^T u}}$$
which only works if the sum of elements of $b$ is greater than zero.
If this is the case, then you can set $v_2,\ldots,v_n$ to be the orthogonal complement of $b$, e.g. by computing an orthogonal basis of $b$ treated as a column matrix (which you can do by a full-sized LQ factorization).
Finally, $\lambda_2,\ldots,\lambda_n$ can be set to any arbitrary positive number (but the value $1$ would result in a $B$ with the best condition number). You can then form $B$ by summing up all these parts.

Comment: Thank's but I didn't get that:"e.g. by computing an orthogonal basis of b treated as a column matrix (which you can do by a full-sized LQ factorization)" : you mean the orthogonal complement of b? But how to compute it with LQ or others means, I didn't find.

Comment: If you are using matlab, then using the command `[U,S,V]=svd(b)` returns the orthogonal complement of $b$ in the columns of `U` after the first (the first column should be proportional to $b$).